# My index.html Not Loading Assets with Flask Blueprint

Tags: python, flask

when I build the environment and run, I have 2 apps, one is "deceptron" and another is just "home".  https://github.com/NatuMyers/flask-blueprint-appsetup-angular How do I get the index file to properly load app.js, style.css, etc?

I get 404 messages even though they are there and loaded from index.html:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2016 23:34:17] "GET /js/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2016 23:34:17] "GET /sass/materialize.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2016 23:34:17] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2016 23:34:17] "GET /css/vidBg.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Edit:  This is not a duplicate. This uses blueprint + angular unlike the other post.

Comment: The path is most likely relative to the starting path of the Python server (i.e whichever file you run to run the server) and thus, you need to configure Flask to search the proper folders for those requested assets.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't seem to work yet. This is not a duplicate. This uses blueprint + angular

Comment: the fact that you're using blueprints and Angular doesn't make it different from the other question – your underlying problem is still the same, which deals with serving static files using `flask`. Whether or not you use Angular is just a specific project detail that doesn't change your question.

Comment: I still have no idea how to solve this question....this is the problem with SO